# Unsetting an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a file called layout.php which contains

```
<?php
$arrLayout = array(
    "section1" => array(

        "wXBMCLibrary" => array(
            "title" => "XBMC Library",
            "display" => ""
        ),
        "wRecentMovies" => array(
            "title" => "Recent Movies",
            "display" => ""
        ),
        "wRecentTV" => array(
            "title" => "Recent TV",
            "display" => ""
        )
    )
    );
?>
```

What I would like to be able to do is remove any part, for example if I say remove wXBMCLibrary it must remove all of the below

```
 "wXBMCLibrary" => array(
        "title" => "XBMC Library",
        "display" => ""
    ),
```

Is this at all possible? Would you be able to unset the whole piece? What would the coding be?
Regards

Comment: You can't automatically remove all 'below' an element in PHP, but you can loop over the array and manually delete elements after finding the one you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unset($arrLayout['section1']['wXBMCLibrary']);
```

Comment: Could I use variables in place of 'section1' and 'wXBMCLibrary'

Answer (score 0):

This is completely possible through the usage of `unset()` within PHP.  The `unset()` function will remove the item that you specify, so if you specify `unset($arrLayout['section1']['wXBMCLibrary']);` then that will remove the array with the index of 'wXBMCLibrary'.

[PHP - Unset() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)